# Word for Christmas tree that can be taken back

Tags: word-request

What's the name of the service when a Christmas tree is sold in a pot, you only lease it, pay a price plus a deposit, and the tree can be taken back to the seller after Christmas, so they can replant it and sell it again next year, and you get back the deposit? Christmas tree recycling, or does that mean something else?

Comment: *Rent A Christmas Tree*? (Like those *Rent A Car* services.)

Comment: For Lease Navidad

Comment: @npst Okay, I laughed. :D Artemyss, I've never actually heard of anything like this! So I have no idea what to call it specifically. But Damkerng is right that *rent* is the word for paying money to borrow something and then returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no services which do this in a widespread manner as evergreens (the primary type of trees) do poorly when left potted. If a term is needed then "Christmas tree recycling" should be satisfactory.

Comment: "Recycling" to me implies (or at least suggests) they'd destroy the trees and use them as garden mulch or something, not re-plant them to sell again the next year. Maybe "returnable" Christmas trees? Or "reusable" Christmas trees? As you say this service is not widely known, so there's no established term for it.

Comment: I'm saying that the difficulty in keeping evergreens potted and alive for extended periods preclude a successful business model.

Answer (score 0):

These are called *living Christmas trees*.  They are typically only potted during the Christmas season and are replanted at the tree farm for the rest of the year.  These services claim something like a 80% survival rate for these trees.
I heard a story on this on NPR recently.  I'll try to dig up a link.
[Here's a company who does this](http://www.livingchristmas.com/)

Comment: Wow! As it turned out, I actually was quite close. :)